# Error occur while installing Microsoft SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The error message is,
(In dialog box:)
This program has compatibility issues
Microsoft SQL server(2008 and 2008R2)
Microsoft
you can get help online and see more information about this program's compatibility issues.

Comment: The dialog appear to ask you to install a fix for SQL Server that have compatibility issue, after installation of the fix, setup restore the main installation.

Comment: Is it really preventing install or is just informational? Applying the service packs after install should be all that is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> SQL Server 2008 is supported on Windows 8/Windows Server 2012 but
>   requires a minimum of Service Pack 3.

Select `Run this program` (ignore the warning) and then install SQL Server 2008 SP3 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27594.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2012/09/01/installing-sql-server-on-windows-8.aspx